# Django TypedChoiceField choices вставка значений из модели

Tags: django

У меня есть модель `Product` которая имеет `stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()` - это кол-во товара на складе. При создании продукта я создаю рандомное кол-во товара. Товар добавляется в корзину и там я могу поменять кол-во товара. Я хотел бы выводить кол-во то, которое я ввел при создании.

**forms.py**

```
class CartProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=[должно быть product.stock], coerce=int)
    update = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

Как можно передать аргумент данной форме чтобы в параметр `choices` выводился `product.stock`?

**show_cart.html**
Этот файл показывает нам нашу корзину с товаром

```
{% for item in cart %}
    {% with product=item.product %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ product.name }}</td>

            <td>
                <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_update' product.id %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ item.update_quantity_form.quantity }}
                    <button>Обновить</button>
                </form>
            </td>

            <td><a href="{% url 'cart:cart_delete' product.id %}">Удалить</a></td>
            <td>{{ item.price }} руб.</td>
        </tr>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Выглядит это так, как вы можете заметить `select` формы пусты.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот метод который выдает нам эту страницу

```
def cart_show(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'], 'update': True})

    return render(request, 'cart/cart_show.html', {'cart': cart})
```

Как можно ввести значения кол-ва товара на складе в поле `TypedChoiceField`?

Answer (score 0):

Если верно понял задание, то так можете попробовать.

```
quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=[(x.pk, x.stock) for x in Product.objects.all()], coerce=int)
```

Ещё, как вариант, метод *_str_* переопределить.

Comment: пробовал и такое) выводит stock всех продуктов, но не данного, эх

Answer (score 0):

Если всё правильно понял, то можно попробовать вот так, в отображении формы будет выведено текущее значение у item:

```
for item in cart:
    item['update_quantity_form'] = CartProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'], 'update': True}, instance=item)
```

Comment: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Comment: Возможно item.quantity, не знаю как у вас модель выглядит, но в целом не понимаю к чему initial во view-функции